# NSMetadataQuery NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope Search Root Directory Only?

Tags: nspredicate, subdirectory

I am using the NSMetaDataQuery to search for iCloud documents, as recommended, but it's also searching sub-directories.  Is there any way to have it search only the root directory?  My code at the moment is...

```
        NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
        _query = query;
        [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                             @"%K == %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, optionsFilename];
```

Thanks!
Ray

Answer (score 3):

I hope it isn't too late for my answer...

I have the same issue but after a while I found a way to get this done: Compare resource URL without last path component against desired directory path.

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent.path == %@", argumentArray: [NSMetadataItemURLKey, iCloudDocsURL.path])
```

This predicate works like a charm!

Cheers